# Register Page Template from Plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, templates, page-template

I'm trying to figure out how to properly register a page template (and all of the associated assets, like CSS and Images) from a plugin. Basically, I've created a landing page that I want to live outside of the Theme, so I can use it on multiple websites.

My code was as follows:

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'custom_page_template' );
function custom_page_template( $page_template )
{
    $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/custom-page-template.php';
    return $page_template;
}
```

But I'm not seeing the page template within WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You misunderstand what `page_template` does.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/page_template) It does not create a new template that you will "show up" somewhere and that you can use. It replaces the `page.php` template provided by the theme.

I think that what you want is `template_redirect`:

```
function custom_page_template( $page_template ) {
  if (is_home()) {
    get_header();
    echo 'do stuff';
    get_footer();
  }
}
add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'custom_page_template' );
```

Or `template_include`:

```
function custom_page_template( $page_template ) {
  if (is_home()) {
    $page_template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'custom-page-template.php';
    return $page_template;
  }
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'custom_page_template' );
```

Comment: It seems that hooking into `template_redirect` can break any code that may be hooked into `template_redirect` after your plugin. I would expect a workaround is to set a high integer priority in `add_filter` so that your plugin hooks last, but if two plugins do this, it would cause a conflict where whoever hooks last loses. Any thoughts on this? https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/template_redirect-is-not-for-loading-templates/